# how to perform factor calculation using sliding windows with elements from different columns?

Tags: sql, dolphindb, factors

Suppose there is a table with 6 columns: “date”, “symbol”, “a”, “b”, “c”, and “d”. I intend to calculate a factor with a sliding window of length 10, grouped by “symbol“.

I intend that the first 9 rows of each sliding window take the values of “a“ and “b“, while the last row takes the values of “c“ and “d“. How to achieve this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For self-defined factors that cannot be calculated using a built-in function, we can only create a user-defined function to define the calculation rules within the window, and then use the higher-order function `moving` to calculate the sliding window. For common factors that can be calculated using a built-in function, such as `msum`, you can use the script `window(sum, a, -9:-1) + c` to sum up the values of "a" in the first 9 rows and then add the value of "c".